# How do I check if an array contains anything else than a specific value in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

```
arr=( d d d a)
```

The code below is supposed to check if it contains `d`. Is there a similar way to check if it contains anything else than `d`?

```
if [[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" d "* ]]; then                                         
 echo "arr contains d"  
fi
```

Comment: @iamauser, in your edit you altered the code presented in the question.  To be sure, the original code did not work, but the revised code is not altogether correct either (it can return a false positive if the array contains `' d'`, `'d '`, or `' d '`).  That aspect of your edit was not appropriate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The formatting obscured the actual code in the original question. The edit is valid.

Comment: I just make it `coded`. How can I undo it ?

Comment: @iamauser, my bad.  I failed to look at the markdown view of the edit.  It's fine.

Comment: But in any case, the original code is indeed flawed.

Comment: alright, not touching it any further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're not using space in Array elements you can use:

```
[[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" "[^d]" "* ]] && echo "array has non-d element" || echo "no"
```

**Testing:**

```
arr=(d d d a)
[[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" "[^d]" "* ]] && echo "array has non-d element" || echo "no"
array has non-d element

arr=(d d d)
[[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" "[^d]" "* ]] && echo "array has non-d element" || echo "no"
no
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the array and check each element. There might be a better method than the following, but this one should work :

```
# Loop over the array elements
for i in "${arr[@]}"; 
do 
  # Check if it is not d
  if [[ "$i" != "d" ]]; then 
    echo "array element is not d. it is $i"; 
  fi 
done
```

Comment: Is there anyway possible to do this without a loop? I just want to know if anywhere in the array there is an element that does not equal "d". Don't need to know which element or what it equals. Just need to know that there is an instance that does not equal "d".  Thanks