# array - if not all elements the same, 1 liner

Tags: arrays, regex, bash

Thanks to the answer of anubhava here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32873200/12365630)  we know how to search inside an array if there is another element not like the rest of them, so i tried something similar to find out it does not work.

example, all elements should be UP, if one (or more) is not then give a message

```
$ arr=(UP DOWN UP UP)
$ [[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" "[^U]" "* ]] && echo "array has non-UP element(s)" || echo "no"
no
```

it should state that there is an non-UP (second, that DOWN) element in that array but it fails. probably it matches only letters and not words..

how should that part "[^U]" be to get this fixed?

also it would be nice to understand this better, can someone explain in detail this whole part
`*" "[^U]" "*`  ?

Comment: Using the `=~` operator is more appropriate here and doesn't require setting `extglob` or putting extra space characters:    `[[ ${arr[*]//UP} =~ ^\ *$ ]] && echo "array has non-UP element(s)" || echo "no"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this solution to work, you have to first use the command `shopt -s extglob` to enable extended globbing:

```sh
[[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" "!(@(UP|*" "*))" "* ]] && echo "array has non-UP element(s)" || echo "no"
```

Essentially what this does is it puts a space around every element and checks to see if they match a glob. `${arr[*]}` is every element in the array joined by spaces, and `" ${arr[*]} "` puts two more spaces around the array, so it ends up looking like `" UP DOWN UP UP "`. The glob checks to see if the string has any amount of text (`*`), followed by a space (indicating the start of an element), followed by something that's not `!(...)` "UP" or (`@(...|...)`) anything with a space.